# Rational numbers appear in reduced forms

Tags: ruby, rational-numbers

I want to save a rational number `3/12` in a variable using this code:

```
rNo = Rational(3, 12)
# => 1/4
```

but ruby reduces the number to `1/4`.

Can anybody please tell me how to keep the numbers as I write them?

Comment: `3/12` is equivalent to `1/4`. If you want to distinguish them, then you need something other then a rational number: a string, perhaps.

Comment: Is this a Ruby question? Is this a programming question? Is this not a math question?